# Change default location for packages in Umbraco

Tags: configuration, umbraco7

By default local packages are saved in Umbraco project to Media/created-packages folder. Is it possible to change the default location? I'm using Umbraco 7.11

Comment: Are you talking about the xml file that registers which packages you install through the backoffice? My `createdPackages.config` changes have always been saved to `App_Data/packages/created/createdPackages.config`. Do you have a ` App_Data/packages/created/createdPackages.config` file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @bowserm I mean the location of the actual package, not the config file

Comment: Ah. Are you talking about creating your own package? Or are you talking about installing a package through the backoffice?

Comment: I am talking about creating custom packages, hence I was asking about where are they saved and if that location can be configured?